# Mongoose data from server (Nodejs) not displaying / .get() too late

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am just wondering if I am doing anything wrong.  I save data to mongo like this:

```
router.route('/userAdditionalData')
//updates current user data
.put(function(req, res, next){

    UserAdditionalInfo.findOne({userRef: req.body.userRef}, function(error, foundUser){

        if(error){
            console.log('Error in adding additional User Data: ', error);
            return done(null);
        };

        if(foundUser){

            foundUser.update(req.body, function(error, count){
                res.send(200, foundUser)
            });

        }

        else{

            var addData = new UserAdditionalInfo();

            addData.middleName = req.body.middleName;
            addData.employer = req.body.employer;
            addData.jobDescription = req.body.jobDescription;
            addData.userRef = req.body.userRef;

            addData.save(function(error, data){

                if(error){
                    return res.send(500, error)
                }

                return res.send(200, data);
            });
        }   
    });
})
```

And I get the data like this:

```
.get(function(req, res){
    UserAdditionalInfo.find(function(err, data){
        if(err){
            return res.send(500, err);
        }
        return res.send(200, data);
    });
});
```

In my angular controller, when I get the data using $http.get():

```
$http.get('/api/userAdditionalData').then(function(response){

    console.log('response -> ', response.data[0]);
    controller.userAdditionalData = response.data[0];

});
```

The console perfectly logs my response, but when I log the *controller.userAdditionalData* I get `undefined`.  Now, when I put a `$timeout` of `10` around my console.log:

```
$timeout(function(){
    console.log(controller.userAdditionalData);
}, 10);
```

everything works fine.  Which means that my data is being set too late.  Is there something that I am not doing/doing wrong?

Comment: where are you using `console.log(controller.userAdditionalData);`?

Comment: outside of my .get(), but it is defined earlier in the controller.  So basically it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beacause the async paradigm in JavaScript. If you make an async call and outside make a log, probably prints undefined because the async is not finished. Wait for the async call with a promise or multiple promises if in a loop, when the promise ends , then you can log the value or use it.

Comment: Thanks,  took me a while to figure it out, but finally did.